# Why there is no Tag for onepiece-treasurecruise

Tags: discussion

Here is the game link which i play in my android

http://onepiece-treasurecruise.com/en/

i am just asking because i have some questions.

Comment: This is more of a meta-topic, but for a quick answer: On Stack Exchange, tag can't exist if there is no question for it. If there is a question for something that doesn't have a tag yet, such a tag will be created. If you can't create it yourself, you can ask others to do so in the (tag-wise incomplete) question. Perferibly in the comments.

Comment: @DJ Pirtu is right, however I wanted to add that you need 300 Reputation in order to create a tag. Also, if noone else subscribes to the tag it just might be useless. Also, you can simply ask about the game without there being a tag. That is not forbidden.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray, actually it's 300 rep http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @DJ Pirtu damn, you are right. Must have had some other StackExchange site in mind. However my point stands :p

Comment: @Crowley - unlike most other SE sites, Arqade favours breadth (lots of small topics) rather than depth (a few large topics) when it comes to tagging. Ergo a game tag is useful so long as there is a single question asked on it. Because of this, a tag on Arqade won't get removed if it only has one question (as what happens on some other sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that the quesion's migrated, here's my comment as an answer:

On Stack Exchange, tag can't exist if there is no question for it. If there is a question for something that doesn't have a tag yet, such a tag will be created. If you can't create it yourself, you can ask others to do so in the (tag-wise incomplete) question. Preferibly in the comments.

The question does require **a** tag to be added. Untill the proper tag is created, the usual recommendation is to us the platform tag.

Anybody with [300 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) can create the tag and post it as a edit suggestion. Some high rep users can even edit the question directly, without needing to go through the suggestion process.